# is it possible to display an image from a xml file using DOM?

Tags: javascript, xml, image, dom

I'm new to this forum and I want to ask a question on how can I make an image from an xml file to load itself using DOM? here is my code and I don't know what's wrong in it. Can anyone help me debug this please? thanks :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showImage(){
        var xmlimg = document.getElementById("myphoto");
        var photo=xmlimg.getElementsByTagName("photo");


        var showImg =document.createElement("div");
        showImg.createElement("IMG");
        showImg.setAttribute("src","sunset.jpg");

        var getImage=document.createElement("div");
        getImage.setAttribute("class","fileko");

        showImg.appendChild(getImage);

        var viewimage= document.createTextNode(photo.getElementsByTagName("fileko")[0].firstChild.data);
        getImage.appendChild(viewimage);

        getImage.appendChild(viewimage);

        var getAttr=document.createElement("div");
        getAttr.getAttribute("stolen");
        showImg.appendChild(getAttr);


       document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(showImg); 

    }
</script>

    </head>
    <body onload="showimage()" style="display:none">
    <xml id="myphoto" >
    <photo kind="stolen">
    <fileko>sunset.jpg</fileko>
    <desc>Sunrise</desc>
    </photo>
    </xml>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an Ajax request to the xml file and get the data needed.  Then create an Image element with the proper properties based on retrieved data and then append that image element into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible just follow below code and you will get that easily what you need to do. this is my code  that is fetching data from xml file

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my xml look like this
[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvM5b.png)